# How to create all possible graphs that connect all vertices?

Tags: functions, function-construction, graphs-and-networks

How can I generate all labelled *connected* simple graphs on `n` vertices?

In the image below, I drew examples with number of vertices `n = 3` and `n = 4`.

For `n = 3`, there are only 4 graphs that connect all vertices.
For `n = 4`, I only drew some as there are many more so did not draw all here.

I would like to create a function that if I input the number of vertices then it generates all graphs like the image below.

Any idea to do this?

The layout of graphs is not important but I want to label vertices's names with number or letters. Self-loop is not possible and there is only one edge between two vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For small $n$, one can use:

```
allEdges[n_]:=Flatten[Table[UndirectedEdge[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,i+1,n}]];
allConnected[n_]:=Select[Map[Graph[Range[n],#,VertexLabels->Automatic]&,
                             Subsets[allEdges[n]]],ConnectedGraphQ];
allConnectedUpToIso[n_]:=DeleteDuplicates[allConnected[n],IsomorphicGraphQ];
```

**Example:**

```
allConnectedUpToIso[4]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't create all graphs like I mentioned above. Two graphs with same shape but vertices different are considered different in my case.

Comment: Please try `allConnected[4]`, it will return all those graphs.

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: Better practice is to accept the answer if it answers what you asked instead of writing  "thank you".

Comment: In general, `DeleteDuplicates[list, IsomorphicGraphQ]` is very inefficient. The better way to do this is `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, CanonicalGraph]`. However, OP was asking for labelled graphs.

Answer (score 5):

A hopefully efficient approach to generate all possible adjacency matrices as bit fields. In a first step, we filter those which have a sufficient number of edges to be connected. In a second step, we filter connected graphs.

```
In[161]:= 
n = 5; (* no of vertices *)
k = n (n - 1)/2; (* max number of edges *)

In[163]:= symmetrize = # + Transpose[#] &;

In[164]:= 
adjmats = 
  symmetrize@PadRight[TakeList[#, Range[n] - 1], {n, n}] & /@ 
   IntegerDigits[Range[2^k] - 1, 2, k];

In[165]:= graphs = Select[
   AdjacencyGraph /@ Select[adjmats, Total[#, 2]/2 >= n - 1 &],
   ConnectedGraphQ
   ];

In[166]:= Length[graphs]
Out[166]= 728
```

We can convince ourselves that the code is correct by comparing counts with https://oeis.org/A001187

I did not benchmark this against other solutions.

Comment: Somehow this is slower than the user293787's answer on my laptop using AbsoluteTiming. user293787's method takes 0.0930639 and this method takes 0.2760455 for 5 vertices.

Comment: The link is interesting.

Comment: It's interesting that this is slower. I don't have the time to look into why, but I suspect that in Mathematica building a graph from an adjacency matrix is just slower than building one from an edge list.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

This is probably not what OP meant (as pointed out by @user293787) but I understood it as all vertices have to be connected somewhere instead of all vertices have to be connected together. If it was the former case my answer would be:

```
n = 4;
Graph[Range[n], UndirectedEdge @@@ #, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
   VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[n], ImageSize -> 50] & /@ 
 Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], {Floor[n/2], ∞}], 
  Length[Union[Flatten[#]]] == n &]
Clear[n]
```

[image]

[image]

And just a small portion of all 768 graphs for `n=5` (for `n=6` there is already 27449 graphs):

[image]

And this is for the latter case (selection by `ConnectedGraphQ` added to previous code):

```
n = 4;
Select[Graph[Range[n], UndirectedEdge @@@ #, 
    VertexLabels -> Automatic, VertexCoordinates -> CirclePoints[n], 
    ImageSize -> 50] & /@ 
  Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], {Floor[n/2], \[Infinity]}], 
   Length[Union[Flatten[#]]] == n &], ConnectedGraphQ]
Clear[n]
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the requirements. I took it as any vertex must be connected somewhere, not that all vertices have to me connected together.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I actually meant to say all vertices connected together.