# Why does ReplaceAll not work here?

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks, replacement

Why does this not change the names of the vertices?

```
Graph[List[1,2,3], List[UndirectedEdge[1,2], UndirectedEdge[1,3]], List[Rule[VertexLabels,List[Automatic]]]] /. {1->a,2->b,3->c}
(*  the graph =  allConnected[3] *)
```

The graph is obtained using the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275781/82512).

```
allEdges[n_] := 
  Flatten[Table[UndirectedEdge[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, i + 1, n}]];
allConnected[n_] := 
  Select[Map[Graph[Range[n], #, VertexLabels -> Automatic] &, 
    Subsets[allEdges[n]]], ConnectedGraphQ];
allConnectedUpToIso[n_] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[allConnected[n], IsomorphicGraphQ];
```

Why does this not work?  I want to change the vertice names to my customized names.

I know that I can convert the graph to edge lists and then try the rule (already tried). 
 I'm curious why it does not work and can we try the rule without converting them to edge lists?

Comment: In order not to make things too complicated, perhaps you could ask your question in a concrete case. For example, why does `Graph[List[1,2,3], List[UndirectedEdge[1,2], UndirectedEdge[1,3]], List[Rule[VertexLabels,List[Automatic]]]] /. {1->a,2->b,3->c}` not change the names of the vertices?

Comment: I think has to do with fact that `Graph` transforms to a raw object, similar to sparse arrays, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/using-replaceall-on-sparsearray/13792#13792). I think this question can actually be considered a duplicate of that question, because the answer explicitly mentions `Graph`.

Comment: Bit of a hack, but this works: `ToExpression[
 StringReplace[
  ToString[InputForm[allConnected[3]]], {"1" -> "a", "2" -> "b", 
   "3" -> "c"}]]`

Comment: Following the link in the link above leads to a code in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95317/86543) for obtaining the list of functions where presumably replacements do not work : `EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"]//EntityList`

Comment: Good to know. I have never thought about something that big like Graph can be atomic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `ReplaceAll` on a `Graph` object because it is [`AtomQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html).  Use [`VertexReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html) to replace vertices in a `Graph`.

In your code you would use

```
VertexReplace[#, {1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c}] & /@ allConnected[3]
```

[image]