# How to convert units from percent per year to real number with CountryData?

Tags: units

I have `CountryData` coming in via e.g.

```
Entity["Country", "Australia"][
  EntityProperty["Country", "GDP",
   {"CurrencyUnit" -> "Constant2000USDollar", 
    "TimeSeriesOperator" -> "AnnualGrowthRate"}
  ]
]
```

Which returns

```
-0.00383656% per year (* unit: percent per year *)
```

My desired output is `-0.0000383656` (i.e. as purely a decimal number).

I am surprised by how hard it has been to find an answer. Despite this question being very simple, I can't find a way with `Quantity`, `NumberForm`, etc.

Comment: I'd just do `QuantityMagnitude[r]/100` where `r` is your result you obtained from that long command.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sAdE.png)  `-0.0000383656`

Comment: Simply take the first part of your result: `yourresult[[1]]`

Comment: @DanielHuber cool, simple solution. Is there a way one can investigate the structure/parts of an object that would have let me figure this out?

Comment: Every object in MMA is like an array. With obi[[0]] you can get the head and with obi[[i,j..] all the  parts. Note, this does not work for atomic objects , they consist of only the head.

Comment: Also with `FullForm` you can see the structure of the returnvalue: FullForm[r] gives you Quantity[-0.0038365585665900404`,Times["Percent",Power["Years",-1]]]

Comment: Or also `TreeForm` if you want something more visual. `TreeForm` can be nice when you have nested structures. For example compare `{{{s, l}}, {{u, {j}}}} // TreeForm` with `k[s + l] + o[u + m[j]] // TreeForm` (the variables should not be assigned a value). That shows how symbolically a list, an expression or a wrapper it's basically the same with different letters. The only thing I would add is that mathematica functions sometimes treat lists differently than other objects but often functions that work for lists work for expressions.

Comment: Or if you want a nicer output maybe `ExpressionTree` but that one is newer and I do not know how reliable it is.

Comment: `FullForm`, `TreeForm` and `ExpressionTree` might lead to expressions that are too lengthy at times in which case you can consider `InputForm` after getting familiar with outputs of `FullForm`

Comment: `FullForm`, `TreeForm` and `ExpressionTree` might lead to expressions that are too lengthy at times in which case you can consider `InputForm` after getting familiar with outputs of `FullForm`. At a more advanced level note that some objects like `Graphs` that are `AtomicQ` might not seem to be when you look  at the `FullForm` as it would seem that you could use `Part` or `Replace`. But `FullForm` just provides a visualization of the structure if the object is `AtomicQ` and does not show all of the information in the internal representation/code of the object.

Comment: For a recent discussion with `ReplaceAll` not working even though `FullForm` would suggest it to be possible see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275837/86543. For a list of Atomic objects see `EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"]//EntityList
`

Answer (score 2):

Collection of answers in the comments (many thanks to those commenters):

1. `QuantityMagnitude[%]`
2. `%[[1]]` or `Part[%, 1]`

And inspect the output with `FullForm[%]`, `TreeForm[%]`, and `ExpressionTree[%]`.